# Do I need to REVOKE permissions when a table is dropped

Tags: postgresql, database-migration

As part of a migration I create a table and grant permissions to a user. Do I need to `REVOKE` the permissions on my downgrade migration which already drops the table?

```sql
--- up.sql

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 (id int primary key);

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE ON TABLE table1 TO user1;
```

```sql
--- down.sql

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;
```

Do I need to add the following or is it implicit?

```sql
REVOKE SELECT, INSERT, DELETE ON table1 FROM user;
```

Comment: Give it a try, most likely you get this error message: [42P01] ERROR: relation "table1" does not exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you drop an object, all its privileges are also gone. That is because privileges are stored on the object itself: in the case of a table, the privileges are stored in the `relacl` column of the `pg_class` table (where all tables are stored).